# Sorting a Result in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am using a code to extract a value from a file and I have a loop that does this process for 12 times so in total I receive 12 numbers shown on the screen seperetaly and I want them to be sorted from small to big in the end but I could not do it with the `sorted()` code.

The result looks like

```
57423.8674915
57423.8821137
57423.8891771
57423.856707
57423.8604281
```

I  so I want them to be in order from small to large but they are not an array or anything they are just 12 numbers taken from different files shown on the screen..

This is the code I use :

```
for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    a = hdulist[0].header['JD'] - 2400000.5
    sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
    print  a
    hdulist.close()
```

Here a is 12 numbers taken from a .fits file but in random order, so I want them to be in
an order from small to larger.

Comment: Can you show the code you have attempted for this?

Comment: Why couldn't you do it with `sorted()`?

Comment: do you want each column sorted? or all the data sorted by one column? we need to see an example of success.

Comment: I have added the code i used for the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing them as you get them (in which it can't be sorted as you are printing it one by one) read it into a list (python doesn't technically have arrays) and sort that list, then have a loop that reads out the numbers. The code below should help

```
myList = []
for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    a = hdulist[0].header['JD'] - 2400000.5
    myList.append(a)
    hdulist.close()


for item in sorted(myList):
    print item
```

Comment: I receive an error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add' when I do the code you suggesseted

Comment: Thank you very much, that works now! The thing i don't understand is what is the result i am getting is it an array, list or what is it and why sorted() does not work. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So Python doesn't have an Array, so its technically 'a' list. What is your a variable in the code, is that your list?

Comment: I have a file that has lots of variables and I only take one, which is named as JD on that file and my "a" is the thing that corresponds to JD from each .fits file

Comment: So, from the looks of it what it is doing is sorting each line one by one. So the way it sees it is your telling it order "123123". Then you come by again and say order "344342" but you never really tell it to order "1232321" and "344342" so it just keeps ordering one line at a time. My code gets all of the numbers, then it orders them all at once. Does that make sense?

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped! Good luck!